# Error "Cannot find module 'crypto'" in WalletConnect module

Tags: cryptography, wallet-connect

I am using hedera-wallet-connect and I encounter an error related to a missing module 'crypto' when attempting to run the application,

[Image describing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7jST.png)
[Image describing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM3iR.png)

Steps to Reproduce:
Run the application using the provided setup.
Navigate to the login page.(the error occurs on every page using hedera-wallet-connect under the hood, not only login)
Observe the error message stating "Cannot find module 'crypto'".

Additional Information:
This issue seems to be related to the hedera-wallet-connect library and also same behavior when using hashconnect .

Environment:
Node.js Version: v21.7.1
NextJS Version: 14.1.0
hedera-wallet-connect Version: 1.0.6
hashconnect Version: 3.0.13

Please let me know if further information or assistance is required to address this issue.

Thank you.

I tried using webpack.config.js but nothing worked